# Do I use preview-latex correctly?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I open a LaTeX file in Emacs, and press C-c C-p C-b (M-x preview-buffer) to generate math/graphics previews for the entire buffer. I find that a pdf file is generated with each page containg a math formula.

I then move cursor to the beginning of an equation, press C-c C-p C-p (M-x preview-at-point). But the equation is folded up. Here is before and after the key hitting:

[image]

[image]

Do I use preview-latex correctly? Why is there no equation rendered for the first line? Thanks.